# Strange casting (.asInstanceOf[T]) behaviour in Scala 2.9

Tags: generics, scala, types, casting, parallel-processing

I am writing a piece of software for parallel computations. The software is totally generic, and thus I need a class to wrap sequences.

Right now, I am experiencing strange behaviour in my map-function. A map function takes a function-object as input, which can output a different type than its input argument.

Take a look at the following code:

```
class SeqMPJ[T](indexedSeq: IndexedSeq[T]) {

  val seq = indexedSeq.view //Lazy
  val freeRanks = MPJEnv.getFreeRanks(seq.size)
  //Get n free ranks
  val commGroup = MPI.COMM_WORLD.group.Incl(freeRanks.toArray)
  //Communicator for this sequence
  val comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Create(commGroup)

  val opIndex = globalRank % seq.size
  var operand: Any = seq(opIndex)

  if (!isOnline)
    error("Cannot use MPJ-abstractions outside parallelize body...")

  //Only works for p=n now
  def mapMPJ[U](f: (T) => U): SeqMPJView[U] = {
    if (freeRanks.contains(globalRank)) { //Process is part of this operation
      operand = f(operand.asInstanceOf[T])
    }
    return new SeqMPJView(operand.asInstanceOf[U], comm, freeRanks)
  }
```

...

Notice that in the function `mapMPJ[U](f: (T) => U):SeqMPJView[U]` , the function f has input type T and output type U. This means, after applying f to the variable "operand", operand is of type U, however, this happens inside the if-block. In other words, depending on the state, operand has either type U or T. Now, when I cast to U, it always succeeds. Even when the condition in the if-block fails. As I see it, the program should fail when casting operand.asInstanceOf[U] if the program does not enter the if-block.

An example usage is in this matrix multiplication:

```
val M = 2
val N = 2

val A = Array(
  Array(1.0, 2.0),
  Array(3.0, 4.0))

val B = Array(
  Array(1.0, 2.0),
  Array(3.0, 4.0))

val Bt = B.transpose

/*
 * DNS using underlying MPI
 */
parallelize(args) {

  for (i <- 0 until M; j <- 0 until N)
    A(i) zip Bt(j) mapMPJ { case (a, b) => a * b } reduceMPJ (_ + _)

  if (globalRank == 0)
    println("CHECK RESULT:\n" + Matrix(A) * Matrix(B))

}
```

The program compiles and runs perfectly using the newest eclipse scala IDE. I haven't tried other compilers, but it's probably me being blind, but I spent so much time, so I hope for some help :)

**edit**

There's an implicit conversion from Array to seqMPJ, FYI.

Comment: The way you are tricking the typechecker is disturbing and probably unnecessary. Have you considered using Either[A, B] as the type of operand? The comment hints that you may not need operand in the other state.
Do you want to apply the function later to operand, if the if is not taken? In that case, I'd use:
`trait Result[U] {
def res: U
}
case class Computed[U](res: U) extends Result[U]
case class ToCompute[T, U](t: T, f: T => U) extends Result[U] {
def get = f(t)
}`
and I'd make what you now call `operand` have type `Result[U]` (and rename it).

Comment: It is the case that I do NOT need operand in the case where the if-clause fails. However, I must return a new SeqMPJView! Either[A,B]? Is Either a keyword?

Comment: `Either` is a standard Scala datatype; probably `Option` should be used in defining `SeqMPJView`, to specify that you don't need to pass it a value. `Either[A, B]` allows to supply a value of either type `A` or type `B`, like a _type-safe_ union.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting is just you asserting to the compiler that you know what you are doing and what the type really is, when it comes to generic type arguments.  They're all really just `AnyRef`==`java.lang.Object` (or whatever the bounding type is).  If you lie to it, it will believe you (until there is a runtime exception caused by having the wrong type somewhere that the type is used).  If you want to know whether you've got the correct type, you have to check with manifests.

Here's an example:

```
def example[A: ClassManifest,B: ClassManifest](a: A) = {
  if (implicitly[ClassManifest[A]] <:< implicitly[ClassManifest[B]]) a.asInstanceOf[B]
  else throw new Exception("Wrong!")
}
```

If you try a cast that won't work, this will yell at you:

```
scala> example[List[Int],List[String]](List())
java.lang.Exception: Wrong!
```

You can modify your code accordingly, e.g.

```
implicitly[ClassManifest[U]].erasure.isAssignableFrom(operand.getClass)
```

Comment: Care to elaborate this part:

'implicitly[ClassManifest[A]] <:< implicitly[ClassManifest[B]]'

And I'm not sure I understand the purpose of this:

implicitly[ClassManifest[U]].erasure.isAssignableFrom(operand.getClass)

Comment: implicitly[ClassManifest[U]].erasure.isAssignableFrom(operand.getClass) is a runtime test for type compatibility: it returns true if you can assign operand to a variable of type U, that is, it the runtime type of operand is a subtype of U (
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class))

Comment: @Felix - `<:<` means "is a subclass of", and `implicitly[ClassManifest[A]]` means "get the actual class manifest corresponding to `A`".  Blaisorblade has explained the other call, so it turns out they're both runtime checks that make sure the type is what you ask for (or a subtype thereof).

Comment: I accepted the answer because it explains why my code compiles.